# Laravel Post Request Login by Curl

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I'm renting a service(elaborated on Laravel), but he don't have functionality what I need.
And I need to elaborate a parser.
I'm trying to authenticate by curl, but I get a error "TokenMismatchException".

how can i solve this problem ?

```
$laravelLoginUrl = 'http://.../login';

$token = '...';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $laravelLoginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107 
Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
"email=...&password=>...&_token=" . $token);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN: ' . $token,
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN: ' . $token,
));
$answer = curl_exec($ch);
echo $answer;
```

Comment: Laravel generates a CSRF Token on each active session. If your request's token does not match the one generated by Laravel you get the `TokenMismatchException`. See the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf). You CAN disable the CSRF for a specific route, but for login, that would likely not be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

The TokenMismatchException could be caused by the CSRF Middleware. Try disabling it for the specific routes by removing             `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,` from `app\Http\Kernel.php` under `protected $middlewareGroups`

Be careful that this disables it for all of your web routes. If you only want to disable it for specific routes you can do so by going to `app\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php` and whitelisting for example the api route group by putting `api/*` under the except array

Comment: How I said before, I don't have sources of project.

Comment: Fetch the login page, grab csrf token, then post with credentials and csrf token. Very inefficient solution and I recommend you to build an actual api instead of trying to fool the csrf protection

You should be able to find the csrf token under `<meta name="csrf-token" content="your token">`

Comment: I think when I'm trying to get csrf-token, and put it in post request, he changing

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to get page body and parse it first. Because you need token right? Use the same header and cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Check this library to use jwt tokens https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

Comment: I rent a service but I don't have sources.